# making a ajax call to a wcs/fatwire template

Tags: ajax, jsp, wcs

I want to make an ajax call to a Oracle wcs template (page2.jsp) from page1

The problem here is I need to pass the url value dynamically after calling

but this is not loading the page2Url template after executing the ajax script.

here is my script and jsp.But the url is not populated and its not loading the page2 (But if I hardcode the url directly its loading the page2.jsp in the current page)

```
    <render:gettemplateurl  tname="page2" outstr="page2Url" c="Page" cid='<%=ics.GetVar("cid")%>' ></render:gettemplateurl>

<script type="text/javascript">
function loadXMLDoc()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
}
xmlhttp.open('GET','http://test.com<%=ics.GetVar("page2Url")%>',  true );
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make ajax call, do the following:

1. Create CSElement which includes your coding part.
2. Create SiteEntry for this CSElement and click Wrapper=true while creating it.
3. If you want to pass arguments to CSElement, then add parameter names to cache criteria.
4. Make the siteentry URL using satellite:link tag, which will provide you output URL say for eg: ajaxURL.
5. Call this ajaxURL in your script or JS file as required. For eg: call url using ics.getvar("ajaxURL") or if you want to skip 4th step, call directly like /cs/ContentServer?pagename=SiteEntryName&param1=param1Value

I hope this helps.
Cheers!!